# Command for using a page in a template structure if logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having to use ruby to construct interactions with api's, which has been going ok. but now trying to get the layout of the template right. each part of the page, header,footer, side menu and content is in a seperate rhtml file. but in some cases i require the side menu page to be different if the user is logged in. Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your authentication solution, you can check for something like this:

```
<% if @current_user %>
  ... Render menu type 1
<% else %>
  ... Render menu type 2
<% end %>
```

This way you are checking if there is a current_user logged in your app and do the view logic to display a different type of menu.

Comment: new to ruby... view logic? can i not do a simple render menu1.rhtml

Answer (score 1):

I agree with MurifoX, you should make sure that each different menu is rendered as a partial to keep the code clean and simple.

Here is what I have in my application.html.haml (I use HAML):

```
- if user_signed_in?
  = render :partial => "layouts/signed_in_menu"
- else
  = render :partial => "layouts/menu"
```

Comment: and this will work as a php equivalent of a --- <?php
include ('footer.php');
?> --- statement but with the if and else?

Comment: do you not need a file extension?

Comment: No, I don't need a file extension. This is HAML syntax, (see [here](http://haml.info)) with Ruby code embedded. It's basically the same as what MurifoX wrote, but with the two different menues moved to different files ("/layouts/_signed_in_menue.html.haml" and "/layouts/_menu.html.haml"). The files are included when the view is rendered. The <code>render</code> syntax takes care of including the files in the view and will look for appropriate files to render (regardless of file extension). I don't know about the PHP equivalent...